# UbuntuOne client alternative

Tags: ubuntu-one

On Ubuntu 12.04, UbuntuOne client has never worked out for me. It just hangs at "File Sync Starting" everytime. I've used all the workaround terminal commands, but nothing works. Now I'm fed up with the desktop client.

## Is there any other way to use UbuntuOne without the default client?

Any other new fix appriciated!
Thanks!

Comment: The Ubuntu One Website does whatever you wish if you need to upload/download folders/files. But it won't keep you automatically in sync. Anyway if you are experiencing problems you can reach your files right there. Let's wait for somebody drop an alternative. BTW: Ubuntu One's official client is tricky but it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, sorry to hear you're having problems. It would be worth [contacting the U1 support team](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/) who are excellent because they may be able to help. However, there are other ways to access Ubuntu One. The U1 website is one of those ways: you can upload and download your files there. You may also find u1ftp (tutorial and instructions at http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2012/09/11/accessing-ubuntu-one-file-storage-via-ftp-from-any-os) an interesting approach if you're happy to access your data directly in your personal cloud without syncing. I'd recommend contacting the support team, though, if you could; we'd certainly like to fix your problem if we can, and it may help other users with similar problems if there are any.